# How to assign a button a value in react

Tags: reactjs, frontend, survey

I'm creating an application and want to create a component in React for ranking. Where I have a six different buttons with values from 1-6 and want to assign this value if a user press 5, this button should have the value 5.(maybe from a json format file) I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. 
I thought about implementing surveyjs, but this wouln't not suite my application.
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: How far have you come in developing the application? Do you need help in implementing the keypress thing or the idea as a whole?

Comment: I have an application where the users should anwer questions and rank the anwers based on the questions. I have the questioniare form and question so when you answer the question you are supposed to get a new question with same form.
I'm struggling to find any good tutorials on implementing the whole idea as a whole

Comment: I am still not 100% sure on your question but as per my understanding, all you need is https://material-ui.com/components/rating/ component. Also have a look at the react Material UI, it has many inbuilt components.

Comment: This is the prototype,
https://preview.uxpin.com/7fb204007fc97420378cd5c8e987a91e9a28d1bf#/pages/122748926/simulate/sitemap?mode=i

So when you press the score 4 this will be saved

Answer (score 0):

i m gona create a simple component and will show you how you can assign a value to each button and receive it , lets define the buttons values in an object so u can replace them with json file later on.

```
let ratingValue = [{ val: 1 }, { val: 2 }, { val: 3 }, { val: 4 }, { val: 5 }, { val: 6 }];

class RateMyQuestion extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleButtonClicked = this.handleButtonClicked.bind(this);
  }

  handleButtonClicked(buttonNumber, buttonValue) {
    console.log("User Pressed " + buttonNumber + "with Rating of " + buttonValue);
  }

  render() {
    let buttonsMap = ratingValue.map((button, index) => {
      return (
        <button key={index} onClick={this.handleButtonClicked(index, button.val)}>
          {button.val}
        </button>
      );
    });
    return <div>{buttonsMap}</div>;
  }
}
```